# Show or Hide UL based on event handled on another tag or on the previously hidden tag

Tags: javascript

I have a UL like this:

```
<ul id="nav" class="hide">
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
</ul>
```

I also have an anchor tag like this:

```
<a id="show-ul" href="#">Show UL</a>
```

Using Vanilla JS (No JQuery):

I need to show the UL on `mouseover` and keep the UL visible. Only hide the UL if the mouse is moved over any other item: E.g: `Body` or off the `UL` after it is visible.

Preferably `mouseout` on the UL.

Using the code below: The UL is hidden as soon as I mouseout or leave the anchor tag. How do I make the UL stay visible until mouseout on the UL?

```js
(function() {

  var showUl = document.getElementById('show-ul');
  var ul = document.getElementById('nav');

  showUl.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    ul.classList.remove('hide');
  }, false);

  // Example: Hide UL when Mouse out
  ul.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    ul.classList.add('hide');
  }, false);

})();
```

```css
.hide { display:none }
```

```html
<a id="show-ul" href="#">Show UL</a>

<ul id="nav" class="hide">
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The script is at the bottom of the body/page. The code above is just to illustrate what I am attempting to do.

Comment: The whole thing has been implemented a million times with CSS. Are you sure you want JS?

Comment: do you want to show the dropdown until another dropdown opens?